# How do I display equations in TraditionalForm in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am looking to use Mathematica to print equations in `TraditionalForm`.

While I have been successful for some simple ones, I have not for the 2 below.
[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you try to enter them, and what went wrong?

Comment: @acl, like this for example: TraditionalForm[NormalDistribution[Subscript[\[Mu], 1], 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sigma]\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)]]

Comment: this has syntax errors, why should it have worked? I am not sure what the problem is: entering the expression, or why the code you gave doesn't work (in which case, because you have things like `Subscript[[Mu],1]` etc--note the two brackets)

Comment: My question is, I guess: Are you trying to find what the correct expression to produce those is, or how to enter them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard way to integrate over a region in MMA is:

```
Integrate[Boole[x^2 + y^2 < r^2] \[Phi][x,y], {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}]
```

MMA doesn't have a `TraditionalForm` for that, so you have to make one yourself:

1) Type `Integrate[\[Phi][x,y],x,y]`.
2) Change to Traditional Form (using  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd>-T)
3) Select the second integral. Make a subscript using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-_ and x^2+y^2<=r^2 in 2D form

[image: Ready]

As to the second one, as `NormalDistribution` hasn't got a `TraditionalForm` definition you have to type it yourself either following Yoda's recipe or make a definition yourself:

```
Unprotect[NormalDistribution];
NormalDistribution /: 
   Format[NormalDistribution[m_, s_],TraditionalForm] := \[ScriptCapitalN] [m, s]
Protect[NormalDistribution];
```

[image]

or, to make it go both ways, use the [Notation package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html).

Comment: Can't you just cut and paste without going to the underlying cell expression?

Comment: @Simon That's indeed faster. Edited

Comment: I like this better. I thought that `TraditionalForm` won't work on mma expressions inside a text cell, but they do. Makes it convenient to just write the function out and hit ctrl-shift-t. However, this is not a good solution inside an input cell, as executing it will evaluate the integral if it were something that could be integrated.

Comment: @yoda Once I'm out of the edit box I keep on seeing errors. I get in and out several times in a few seconds

Comment: @Sjoerd, would you know how to place a "^" on top of an a sigma ? (to refer to an estimator), Thank You !

Comment: @500 ctrl-& to go to the overscript position, then enter ^ (and if you have a US international keyboard a space as well). OverHat[\[Sigma]] should work too. You might want to look at http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EnteringTwoDimensionalInput.html

Answer (score 9):

I think you're trying to enter these expressions in your text/notes/presentations in mma. Here's an example

```
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(\\\ \)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\
\[Integral]\), \(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + \
\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)] \[LessEqual] \*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \
\(2\)]\)]\)\[CapitalPhi](x,y)\[DifferentialD]x\[DifferentialD]y" // \
TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(X\), \
\(1\)]\)~\[ScriptCapitalN](\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Mu]\), \
\(1\)]\),\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(\[Sigma]\), \(1\)], \
\(2\)]\))" // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

The keystrokes for this one are:

<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>N</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>(</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>,
    <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>)</kbd>

I'll leave the other one to you.